# Is there a C API to get a SELinux file context?

Tags: linux, c, selinux

Is there a way in C to get the SELinux context of a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s [`getfilecon(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getfilecon.3.html) in `libselinux`:

```
char * context;
int easize = getfilecon("/path/to/your/file", &context);
```

If the returned size is non-negative, `context` contains the file’s context.